# Find instances of model A connected to an instance of B with specific ID when A relates to C through B

Tags: filter, model, relationship, loopbackjs

In LoopBack, I have a model `Provider`, which has a 'hasMany' relations with a model `Customer` through model `Appointment`. Model `Customer` itself has a 'hasMany' relation back to model `Provider` through the same model `Appointment`.

How can I find instances of `Customer` related to a given `Provider` whose ID is `aderwaze234`?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like `new Provider({ id: 'aderwaze234', }).customers()` given you have set up relations properly or from the api endpoint `/Provider/aderwaze234/customers`. Have a look at the [docs](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/HasManyThrough-relations.html).

Comment: Thanks so much, Farid! I really appreciate sharing your thought and time. It's been helpful.

Comment: Your welcome. I appreciate it if you could [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/170873) my answer.